# my height does not reach the end

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following code

```
<section id="cuerpo">
<h3>&Uacute;LTIMAS OFERTAS</h3>
<article> <img class="img-responsive" src="img/piso.png">
<div class="iconos-articulos"> 
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/wifi.png"> 
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/bater.png"> 
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/fumar.png"> 
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/mascota.png"> 
</div>
</article>
...
```

---

And I have a background color and does not come down to me, only I get to the end of H2

[image]

so the background gets me to the end I have to put him in the css height: 10000px to section. Then when I change screen contents are not many spaces as there are resolutions calling me less height

Comment: share your css as well, try making a fiddle of your question.

Comment: You are asking for help in debugging code... show us the code.

Comment: "*my height does not reach the end*" - doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Add **clearfix** class

**html**

`<section id="cuerpo" class="clearfix"> --------- </section>`

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```